# Showing/Hiding divs with randomised links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a single page site which shows/hides section on click within the viewport.

This is an example of one of the sections:

```
<section id="question1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="question-container">
                <div class="question-box">
                    <p>What is the answer to this question?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#">
                <div id="cheetah" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
                    <img src="images/cheetah.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <div id="hedgehog" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
                    <img src="images/hedgehog.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The problem I am having is that I don't want section ID's to be the same as the a tag href within it. If that makes sense? This is the jQuery I have already:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //ID array
   var questionArray = ['#question1', '#question2', '#question3', '#question4', '#question5', '#question6', '#question7', '#question8', '#question9', '#question10'];
    //collect sections and place in array
    var sectionArray = [];
    $('section').each(function(){
        sectionArray.push(this);
    })
    //randomise id array
    questionArray.sort(function() {
        return 0.5 - Math.random()
        });
    //Target a elements - attach ID to next question
    for(var i = 0; i < sectionArray.length; i++) {
        var aEl = $(sectionArray[i]).find('a');
        $(aEl).each(function(){
            $(this).attr('href', questionArray[i]);
        })
    }
```

}

Any help?

EDIT:

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/samrbrown/full/aLdgYK/

Comment: I didnt get your problem? can u elaborate with example or something?

Comment: @krishnar I have edited my post with a link to a codepen, hope it's helpful

Comment: Still not clear what you want, so you're saying you don't want the section id "question1" to also be on the <a href="#"> tags?